# Passing an array of sub-arrays to a function, and indexing from that array

Tags: c, arduino

I have not programmed in C in a long time. I am forgetting some fundamentals due to programming in JavaScript for so long, and would like some guidance.

I am making a program to display text on a LED matrix. Each character is represented by a series of 8 digit binary codes which represent columns of pixels. The idea is that for each character in a phrase, the code will fetch the relevant codes for that character and push them into a larger array.

The issue I am having is with passing / indexing an array filled with sub-arrays. When I try to run this code I get the error "invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript".

How can I achieve the functionality I intend to? Here is my code.

```
int A[] = {01111111,10010000,10010000,10010000,01111111,00000000};
int B[] = {11111111,10010001,10010001,10010001,01101110,00000000};
int Space[] = {00000000,00000000};

char alphabet[] = "AB ";

int alphabetB[3] = {A,B,Space};

char phrase[] = "AB BAA";

int getLetterIndex(char letter,char alphabet[]){
  for(int index; index < strlen(alphabet); index++){
    if(alphabet[index] == letter){
      return index;
    }
  }
}


int writePhrase(char phrase[],char alphabet[], int alphabetB[]){
  int phraseB[]={};
  int pos = 0;
  
  for(int charIndex = 0; charIndex < strlen(phrase); charIndex++){
    int index = getLetterIndex(letter,alphabet);
    for(int colIndex = 0; colIndex < sizeof(alphabetB[index]); colIndex++){
      phraseB[pos] = alphabetB[index][colIndex];

      pos++;
    }  
  }
  return  phraseB;
}
      
writePhrase(phrase,alphabet,alphabetB);
```

Thank you!

Comment: `01111111` is an octal number equal to 299593, it pretty sure it is not what you expect. Try using `0b01111111` if your compiler supports this extension

Comment: @tstanisl I may just use different digits than 0 and 1 and convert them to strings to iterate through. Is that a valid approach?

Comment: `char A[] = {0b01111111,`

Answer (score 0):

Problematic line in your code:

- `int A[] = {01111111,10010000,10010000,10010000,01111111,00000000};`
  Wrong type of array, int is 2 byte long. You probably want array of bytes.  Octal and decimal constant for assign byte. Replace with `char A[] = {0x7f, 0x90, 0x90, 0x7f, 0x00};`
- `int alphabetB[3] = {A,B,Space};`
  `alphabetB` isn't two dimensional array. It is array of int. A is address of array A  not array as whole object. It is same as expression  `&A[0]` = address of first element. Replace as `char* alphabetB[3] = {A,B,Space};`
- Function `getLetterIndex` don't return error indication if `letter` is not in `alphabet`.
- `int phraseB[]={};`
  C does not support arrays with a dynamic number of elements. You must define size of array, or initializer list. Also you can not create array as local variable. Local variables is allocated on the stack and it is released at end of the function. Btw function not return array, but address of phraseB on the stack
- `int index = getLetterIndex(letter,alphabet);`
  letter is not defined. Probably you wont pass char from `phrase` like `int index = getLetterIndex(phrase[charIndex],alphabet);`
- Last problem is copy loop. `alphabetB` isn't two dimensional array. You can't do this assigment `phraseB[pos] = alphabetB[index][colIndex];`
  Also here is posibility rewriting stack frame and program hang up.

Look here, how to do matrix control in C.
[maxtrix control example](https://www.deviceplus.com/arduino/display-characters-with-leds-how-to-use-a-matrix-led/)

Comment: The library function `strchr` can replace `getLetterIndex`... https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__string.html#ga4a03589020c79fa0b93673634bef711b